# Import Sets from Excel to CPLEX

Tags: c++, excel, database, cplex

I have the following Sets:

```
{int} Test={1,3,6,8,10};

setof (int) Problem[Test]=[{1,3,5},{8,4},{2,6,7},{2,4},{1}];
```

Execution works fine. Problem look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5y0s.png)

As I do not want to insert the numbers manually to CPLEX, I would like to import it from an ExcelFile.

Importing Test via:

```
{int} Test=...;
```

with:

```
SheetConnection Data("Data.xlsx");
Test from SheetRead(Data, "Data1!A1:A6");
```

In the .dat file.

With the Excel File Format, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HSaM.png)

Is no Problem.

```
{int} Test=...;
setof (int) Problem[Test]=[{1,3,5},{8,4},{2,6,7},{2,4},{1}];
```

works...

Now I also would like to read

```
Problem[Test]=[{1,3,5},{8,4},{2,6,7},{2,4},{1}];
```

From an ExcelFile. The Data look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51eNW.png)

BUT:

```
{int} Test=...;
setof (int) Problem[Test]=...;
```

With

```
SheetConnection Data("Data.xlsx");
Test from SheetRead(Data, "Data1!A1:A6");
Problem from SheetRead(Data, "Data1!B2:B6");
```

Leads to the following Error Messsage:

> The Data element "Problem" of Type {int}[Test] is not supported for
> Spreadsheets

.

Does somebody now how the Excel Input must look like, so that is it supported?

Thanks a lot!
Regards

**In Addition:**

I have one further question.
Your answer works perfectly for Excel file format like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YDax.png)
So, one row with more than one value.
That helped me a lot.

But what about this case:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk6m6.png)

It is a set F[m,i] which might have more than one value in one cell, like e.g. F[1,11] = {1 2}

How can I read that one from an Excel file.
Manually it would look like this:

```
> setof (int) F[X][Y]=[[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{1,2}],[{},{},{},{},{1},{},{2},{},{},{},{}],[{},{4,5},{6},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{4},{5},{6},{}],[{},{},{},{},{},{8},{9},{},{},{},{}]];
```

Whith:

```
{int} X={1,8,11,35,68};
{int} Y={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
```

Thanks a lot!

**Addition:**

I tried your links but actually I don´t really know how to adopt it to my case :( I would be to thankful if you could help me one last time with this.

Let´s assume my excel data file looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1MjR.png)

So each value for j has as many columns as values. In this case there are two column for j = 2 and j = 11 each.

The goal is that my set in CPLEX looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoUea.png)

That would help me very much.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that through strings:

.mod

```
range r=1..4;

string temp[r][1..26]=...;
{int} set[i in r]={ intValue(temp[i][j])| j in 1..26:temp[i][j]!=""};

execute
{
  writeln(set);
}

/*

which gives

[{1 2} {6} {7 8 9} {3 4}]

*/
```

.dat

```
SheetConnection sh("readarrayofsets.xlsx");

temp from SheetRead(sh,"A1:Z4");
```

which is in [OPL Excel examples](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Alex Fleischer! That helped a lot for most of the cases I am dealing with. But in one maybe special case I am not sure how it works. I added my question to the inital. You find it attached below "In Addition"

Comment: Hi, you can mix https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/readarrayofsets.mod and https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/read2Darrayfromexcel.mod

Comment: Thank you really much for your help @Alex Fleischer. I tried to adopt it to my problem but actually I don´t really know how to get it work in detail :( I added the detailed problem again above in the intial question and would be so thankful if you could help me one more time with this